# Best way to keep CRM working offline with PHP

Tags: php, security, localhost, crm, offline

I created a CRM Saas for my client using PHP, jQuery and HTML.

Recently my client has some issues with his network in the office and all the business is shuts down because the CRM is not working while the network is off,

I want to create a solutions for situations like this,

for example i thought that maybe i will create a local copy of the crm and i will make a sync between the database in the server and the local database and in the moment that the network will be down i will redirect the user to the local copy of the CRM

and when the network will run again i will sync the local DB to the server DB and redirect the user to the CRM that is on the server.

but i have 1 issue with this solution,

i dont want the user to have the source files of the CRM,

is there any why to secure this files from him?

thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could install a local server with your flavour of OS, Apache, MySQL etc... and encrypt the local drive to ensure the client cannot access the files at anytime:

**Link for Ubuntu**: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FullDiskEncryptionHowto

If all your web documents (PHP, HTML etc..) are all static, then I'm guessing your database is the only thing which will need to be synced. My advise would be to go down the route of Active->Standby:

**Link for MySQL:** https://grox.net/sysadm/misc/mysql_active-standby_master-master.replication

So basically you will need to configure your sites local DB to be offline but still syncing data from the Active instance. When the local DB is unable to communicate (via heartbeat or ICMP echo) the local DB will become live. This will also need minor DNS configuration or you will need to configure this heartbeat within PHP on each DB connection.

Looking at the above for a singular DB, I'd be more inclined to scrap hosted and keep it local. Just give yourself whatever access is needed to support them (FTP, VNC etc..).

Answer (score 1):

You can encrypt the code. There are several ways to do this, both affecting the PHP code itself or the platform the code is running on.

PHP obfuscators - just a few, you can get more on Google

- http://www.zend.com/en/products/zend-guard
- http://phpshadow.com/
- http://www.fopo.com.ar/ - free

Another way is to install VirtualBox on the client's premises and run the application in a Ubuntu/Fedora/WhateverDistroYouLike box with encrypted filesystem. Whenever you need to update something, you can easily create a new version of the virtual machine, test it at your end and then just installed it on the client's premises (takes few minutes). Encrypted Docker containers may also be worth looking at!